# Wicket get button component text

Tags: wicket

I would like to get the text of a button `submitProceed` and will use it in my code/logic.

- HTML

  <button wicket:id="submitProceed" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-save" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

Is it possible to get the button text `Submit`? Also, how to I change this to `Proceed`?

This is how I initialize my button component:

```
private Component m_btnSubmit;

...

    private Component createForm() {
        Form<Void> result = new Form<>("form");

        ...

        result.add(m_btnSubmit = createSubmit("submit"));

        ...

        return result;
    }

    private Component createSubmit(String wicketId) {
        AjaxButton result = new AjaxButton(wicketId) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onConfigure() {
                super.onConfigure();

                ...

                setOutputMarkupId(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
                super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                super.onSubmit(target, form);

                // TODO: Get button text here
                // Check button text if either `Submit` or `Proceed`
                // Action depending on button text (Also change button text)
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                super.onError(target, form);

                ...
            }

        };

        ...

        return result;
    }
```

**Solution:**

First of All, I would like to thank @Andrea and @martin for their solution, I just tweak it a bit for fit my existing code.

Since I need a span containing the text `Submit` and later be changed to `Proceed`... I need to add a span inside button tag like this:

<button wicket:id="submit" type="button"><span wicket:id="labelSubmit">Submit</span≶</button>

the problem with this, I am getting an error that seems it would not allow button to have a nested component.

Error is something like this:
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Expected close tag for '<button wicket:id="submit" type="button">' Possible attempt to embed component(s) '<span wicket:id="labelSubmit">' in the body of this component which discards its body.

To fix this, I need to change from `button` to `a` so it would look like this:

<a wicket:id="submit" type="submit"><span wicket:id="labelSubmit">Submit</span≶</a>

```
...
IModel m_labelModel = Model.of("Submit");
Label m_labelSubmit = new Label("labelSubmit", m_labelModel);
m_labelSubmit.setOutputMarkupId(true);
...
```

In my button's `onSubmit`:

```
m_labelModel.setObject("Proceed");              
target.add(this);
```

Note that I only did change `m_labelModel`, but I need to add the current button (`this`) so that the change will reflect in the UI.

For those, having the same issue or setup... hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

you should use button's constructor that takes also a model as button's label:

```
IModel labelModel = Model.of("Submit");
new Button<>("submit", labelModel);
```

Than you can use the model to get/set this value

Comment: thru `labelModel` I can set the text to `Submit` or `Proceed` right? Also, I can get the text uing labelModel? how do I add the model to `m_btnSubmit` so that it would reflect in the page on submit?  Also, Do I have to change the html of `btnSumit`? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am a noob with wicket btw :)

Comment: @BorgyManotoy sorry I've just realized that the code I shown was wrong. I was using Form object instead of Button

Comment: let's say the button component is created... how do I change `labelModel` to something like `Proceed` and get reflected in UI or page? My objective is... at first show "Delete"... when it is clicked... it will display or change to "Proceed". I mean the button text will change.

Comment: With you example, it works... my other problem is the changing of button text to "Proceed" when it is clicked. I am getting error when I try to add `labelModel` in `AjaxRequestTarget`... seems it is expecting a component.

Comment: Rigth! You have to add the panel component to AjaxRequestTarget after you changed model. Take a quick look here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_how_to_use_ajax_components_and_behaviors

Comment: is it ok to have a span/label component inside a button? adding `wicket:id="xxx"` results to this error.. `org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Expected close tag for '<button wicket:id="delete" type="button">' Possible attempt to embed component(s) '<span wicket:id="labelDelete">' in the body of this component which discards its body`

Comment: this is the html line: `<button wicket:id="delete" type="button"><span wicket:id="labelDelete">Delete</span></button>`

Comment: I was able to fix the error by changing `button` to `a` tag... then in `target.add()` I added `this` since it is referring to the current AjaxButton (code is in current button's onSubmit).. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `new AjaxButton(String, IModel)` constructor, as Andrea Del Bene suggested, then the model will be used to set the `value` attribute of the button:

```
<button value="Submit"></button>
```

If you need to manipulate the `textContent` of the `<button>`, i.e. `<button>!!!THIS!!!</button>` then you can add a `Label` component as a child:

```
IModel<String> labelModel = Model.of("Submit");
Label label = new Label("labelId", labelModel);
label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
button.add(label);
...
```

In `AjaxButton#onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)` you can update it:

```
labelModel.setObject("New value");
target.add(label);
```

Comment: Do I still need to add a label tag inside button like <button><label wicket:id="labelModel">Submit</label></button>? I asked because I am getting an error.. as if it is not allowed inside button. `org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Expected close tag for '<button wicket:id="submit" type="button">' Possible attempt to embed component(s) '<span wicket:id="labelModel">' in the body of this component which discards its body`

Comment: I tried your sample without label tag inside but I am getting error..  as it cannot find the component with `labelId` in html. When I add label tag inside button like `<button wicket:id="btnSubmit"><label wicket:id="labelId">Submit</label></button>`... the error is the one as what I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I was able to fix the error by changing `button` to `a` tag... then in `target.add()` I added `this` since it is referring to the current AjaxButton (code is in current button's onSubmit).. Thanks! :)